# Unable to run sonarqube scanner from jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

> ```
> Jenkins version -  2.15
> SonarQube version - 2.6.1
> ```

I want to display the SonarQube link on the Jenkins console so that, if someone clicks on it, then it should redirect to the exact analysis in the sonarqube website.

Steps executed:

1. Configured the exclusive Jenkins job to run the pom file and passed "sonar:sonar" as the goal.
2. It was showing me the log and if I click the link in the log it's redirecting to my company's SonarQube account.But I wanted this like a hyperlink in the Jenkins console.
3. Sonar configuration is correct in maven `settings.xml` file, it's correct in manage `Jenkins->configure` the system.
4. In manage `jenkins->global tool configuration-> i have checked "install automatically"`, version 2.6.1 from maven repo.
5. I added configuration in Jenkins job `post-build step->execute sonar scanner`.

But am getting the below error if I run the job.

---

```
Started by user xyz
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/appname
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url reponame.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from reponame.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress reponame.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse feature/branchname^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/feature/branchname^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision afe1ab9f98e98223d9e8a9b6af4ee28282a2b2f7 (refs/remotes/origin/feature/branchname)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f afe1ab9f98e98223d9e8a9b6af4ee28282a2b2f7
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list afe1ab9f98e98223d9e8a9b6af4ee28282a2b2f7 # timeout=10
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
Established TCP socket on 46418
[jobname] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-agent-1.7.jar:/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main /opt/maven/apache-maven-3.3.3 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.60.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-interceptor-1.7.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.7.jar 46418
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/appname/pom.xml sonar:sonar -DskipTests -Dsonar.branch=feature/branchname
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Appname 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) @ Appname2 ---
[INFO] User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load global repositories
[INFO] Load global repositories (done) | time=224ms
[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
[WARNING] Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
[INFO] User cache: /home/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=50ms
[INFO] SonarQube version: 5.6.1
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=147ms
[INFO] Execute project builders
[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=60ms
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=229ms
[INFO] Publish mode
[INFO] -------------  Scan Appname feature/branchname
[INFO] Load server rules
[INFO] Load server rules (done) | time=93ms
[INFO] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname
[INFO] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname/target/sonar
[INFO] Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO] Test paths: src/test/java
[INFO] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[INFO] Index files
[INFO] 49 files indexed
[INFO] Quality profile for java: Sonar way
[INFO] JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname/target/jacoco-it.exec
[WARNING] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] Sonargraph: Skipping projectAppname feature/branchname [com.companyname.xyz:Appname2:feature/branchname], since no Sonargraph rules are activated in current SonarQube quality profile.
[WARNING] ----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor
[INFO] Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 7
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization...
[INFO] JavaClasspath initialization done: 29 ms
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization...
[INFO] JavaTestClasspath initialization done: 10 ms
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan...
[INFO] 48 source files to be analyzed
[ERROR] Class not found: javax.annotation.Nullable
[ERROR] Class not found: org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory
[ERROR] Class not found: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
[ERROR] Class not found: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[ERROR] Class not found: lombok.NonNull
[INFO] Java Main Files AST scan done: 2767 ms
[INFO] 48/48 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Java bytecode scan...
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/xyzabcTransactionApp' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/xyzBusinessException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/ErrorResponse' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/InvalidRequestException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/ResourceNotFoundException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/RandomIdGenerator' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/XmlParser' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/AbstractLocalDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/DefaultPropertiesConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/MySqlLocalDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/RelationalCloudDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/SpringApplicationContextInitializer' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzAuditEventController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzabcEventsController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzabcTransactionController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/ErrorHandlingController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/WorkItemController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzAuditEvent' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzClient' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzPayor' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzProperties' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransaction' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransactionDetails' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransactionRTPC' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/AuditInfoRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchabcSource' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchTransactionInfoRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchTransactionInfoResponse' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/abcSource' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/RtpcAlipRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/TransactionInfo' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/WorkItemRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzClientRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzEventAuditRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzPayorRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzPropertiesRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzRtpcTransactionRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzTransactionDetailsRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzTransactionRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/AuditEventService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/TransactionService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/WorkItemService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/AuditEventServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/TransactionServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/WorkItemServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/test/abcControllerMockTest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/util/abcEventConstants' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/util/TransactionInfoBuilder' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/xyzabcTransactionApp' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/xyzBusinessException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/ErrorResponse' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/InvalidRequestException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/ResourceNotFoundException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/RandomIdGenerator' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/XmlParser' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/AbstractLocalDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/DefaultPropertiesConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/MySqlLocalDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/RelationalCloudDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/SpringApplicationContextInitializer' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzAuditEventController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzabcEventsController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzabcTransactionController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/ErrorHandlingController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/WorkItemController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzAuditEvent' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzClient' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzPayor' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzProperties' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransaction' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransactionDetails' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransactionRTPC' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/AuditInfoRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchabcSource' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchTransactionInfoRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchTransactionInfoResponse' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/abcSource' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/RtpcAlipRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/TransactionInfo' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/WorkItemRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzClientRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzEventAuditRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzPayorRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzPropertiesRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzRtpcTransactionRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzTransactionDetailsRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzTransactionRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/AuditEventService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/TransactionService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/WorkItemService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/AuditEventServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/TransactionServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/WorkItemServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/test/abcControllerMockTest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/util/abcEventConstants' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/util/TransactionInfoBuilder' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/xyzabcTransactionApp' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/xyzBusinessException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/ErrorResponse' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/InvalidRequestException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/Exceptions/ResourceNotFoundException' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/RandomIdGenerator' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/XmlParser' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/AbstractLocalDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/DefaultPropertiesConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/MySqlLocalDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/RelationalCloudDataSourceConfig' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/config/SpringApplicationContextInitializer' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzAuditEventController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzabcEventsController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/xyzabcTransactionController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/ErrorHandlingController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/controller/WorkItemController' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzAuditEvent' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzClient' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzPayor' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzProperties' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransaction' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransactionDetails' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/domain/xyzTransactionRTPC' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/AuditInfoRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchabcSource' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchTransactionInfoRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/PatchTransactionInfoResponse' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/abcSource' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/RtpcAlipRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/TransactionInfo' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/dto/WorkItemRequest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzClientRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzEventAuditRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzPayorRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzPropertiesRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzRtpcTransactionRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzTransactionDetailsRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/repository/xyzTransactionRepository' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/AuditEventService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/TransactionService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/WorkItemService' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/AuditEventServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/TransactionServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/service/impl/WorkItemServiceImpl' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/test/abcControllerMockTest' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/util/abcEventConstants' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[WARNING] Class 'com/companyname/xyz/abcs/util/TransactionInfoBuilder' is not accessible through the ClassLoader.
[INFO] Java bytecode scan done: 56 ms
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan...
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Java Test Files AST scan done: 16 ms
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Package design analysis...
[INFO] Package design analysis done: 6 ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaSquidSensor (done) | time=3277ms
[INFO] Sensor Lines Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor
[INFO] parsing /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname/target/surefire-reports
[INFO] Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor
[INFO] Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=5ms
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=31ms
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer
[INFO] JavaCpdBlockIndexer is used for java
[INFO] Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=64ms
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 34 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 86ms, dir size=327 KB
[INFO] Analysis reports compressed in 90ms, zip size=169 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 79ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonar.digital.companyname.net/dashboard/index/com.companyname.xyz:Appname2:feature%2Fbranchname
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at https://sonar.digital.companyname.net/api/ce/task?id=AVrZFBRyedSPsp5e-zRe
[INFO] Executing post-job org.sonar.plugins.stash.StashIssueReportingPostJob
[INFO] Executing post-job org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.AlertBreaker
[INFO] Executing post-job org.sonar.plugins.buildbreaker.ForbiddenConfigurationBreaker
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.646 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-03-16T16:44:17-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/642M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jobname/pom.xml to com.companyname.xyz/Appname2/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Appname2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/2.6.1/sonar-scanner-cli-2.6.1.zip to /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_261
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:860)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:768)
    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:76)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:68)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:102)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation.forNode(SonarRunnerInstallation.java:64)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.BuilderUtils.getBuildTool(BuilderUtils.java:66)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.performInternal(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:228)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerBuilder.perform(SonarRunnerBuilder.java:270)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:919)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:870)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:781)
    ... 19 more
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Sending e-mails to: xyz.com
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: can you paste the jenkin's console log here?

Comment: Yeah, you need to paste the full stacktrace of that error.

Comment: i have added the console log please check and help me

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here

1. You are not going to be able to link to "the exact analysis", only to the project space, showing the results of the most recent analysis.

   (Note that it's planned to add some "exact analysis" functionality
   this year, but it will not show the project homepage as it was
   immediately after a given analysis, as I suspect you desire.)
2. The most recent version of the Jenkins plugin should automatically provide a link to the project dashboard on the job's home page. The SonarQube Scanners have (almost) always included a link to the project at the end of the analysis log.
3. From the console, it appears that you actually have two analyses configured. The first runs with Maven and completes successfully

   > [INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse https://sonar.digital.companyname.net/dashboard/index/com.companyname.xyz:Appname2:feature%2Fbranchname

   Then the second tries to auto-install SonarQube Scanner and fails.

First, I would recommend removing the configuration of the second analysis. Then I would investigate the infrastructure issues that caused the download failure - assuming you might want to do automatic tool installation some time in the future.

Comment: 1->even that works, 2->it shows a link in the job but i want on the jobs page like "http://eugenedvorkin.com/code-quality-analysis-in-deployment-pipeline-with-gradle-jenkins-and-sonar/"

Comment: 1->even that works, 2->it shows a link in the job but i want on the jobs page like "http://eugenedvorkin.com/code-quality-analysis-in-deployment-pipeline-with-gradle-jenkins-and-sonar/"  3->it was not showing as deprecated when i clicked on it, by the way its post-build step not action. 4->i have modified my question and added the log please check that. I dono if my jenkins can connect to the outside network, can u tell me how to check?and if at all i install that scaner in jenkins server manually, will that solve the problem?

Comment: so if i use the analysis results of maven, then how can i display them as a link in Jenkins job home page?and moreover, now i installed manually sonar scannr/runner in jenkins server and i have unchecked the "install automatically ". it connected but failed with different error.

Comment: 1)i removed the maven analysis 2)i downloaded sonar scanner plugin manually and configured jenkins to use it and it worked properly. I even installed sonarjs plugin for java script and it also worked.

Comment: If this is the solution for your problem, please go ahead and answer your own question.